# Selecting XML Elements Based On Keys Stored In Another Element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Unfamiliar with xsl, so I apologize if this is a common question -

I have some xml that looks something like this (sample is simplified, but is what I'm using to mess around with):

```
<root>
  <items>
    <item>
      <value>1</value>
      <id>1</id>
    </item>
    <item>
      <value>2</value>
      <id>2</id>
    </item>
    <item>
      <value>99</value>
      <id>3</id>
    </item>
  </items>
  <itemList>
    <id>1</id>
    <id>2</id>
  </itemList>
</root>
```

My use case is this: I need to get the Ids out of the item list, and then use those ids to identify the items in "items". Then I need to grab the items' values and pass an arbitrary number of them through an aggregation in order to get the final result I need ("sumItems" is a stand-in for a more complicated recursive template I've implemented). Here is the xsl I have so far, where I'm trying to refine the top with-param select attribute:

```
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:call-template name="sumItems">
      <xsl:with-param name="nodeSet" select="//item/id[text()=1 or text()=2]/.." />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="sumItems">
    <xsl:param name="nodeSet" />
    <xsl:param name="tempSum" select="0" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($nodeSet)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$tempSum" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="$nodeSet[1]/value" />
        <xsl:call-template name="sumItems">
          <xsl:with-param name="nodeSet" select="$nodeSet[position() > 1]" />
          <xsl:with-param name="tempSum" select="$tempSum + $value" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Is it possible for me to do something like this, with some kind of sub-query hanging out in the select?

```
 select="//item/id[text()=(//itemList/id)]/.."
```

I'm running this from .Net XslCompiledTransform, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a key declared with `<xsl:key name="item-by-id" match="items/item" use="id"/>`, then you can use `key('item-by-id', //itemList/id)` to select the `item` elements referenced by the `itemList/id` elements and use `sum(key('item-by-id', //itemList/id)/value)` to compute the sum of the `value` elements.

Comment: This also seems to have worked, so I'll mark it as the answer, since it ended up being nicer to read than my ugly select statement

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this makes me feel smarter or dumber, but the shot-in-the dark guess I posted in the bottom of my question actually seems to have worked when I tossed it in my xsl... I didn't even get a syntax error. Sorry for the trouble - here's the working code:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:call-template name="sumItems">
      <xsl:with-param name="nodeSet" select="//item/id[text()=(//itemList/id)]/.." />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="sumItems">
    <xsl:param name="nodeSet" />
    <xsl:param name="tempSum" select="0" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($nodeSet)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$tempSum" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="$nodeSet[1]/value" />
        <xsl:call-template name="sumItems">
          <xsl:with-param name="nodeSet" select="$nodeSet[position() > 1]" />
          <xsl:with-param name="tempSum" select="$tempSum + $value" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```